# Multiprocess-safe way to share a global object (a queue)

Tags: python, multithreading, logging, multiprocessing, metrics

In a rather large and multiprogramming project, we have a need to create metrics (think of OpenTelemetry or Prometheus). The setup is roughly as follows:

- One main process that controls it children and setups up the various events and queues.
- Generally there is one producer process that reads or pulls data from a server, it adds this data into a multiprocessing queue.
- One or multiple consumer processes that process the data, transform it if necessary and add it to the outbound queue.
- One outbound process that handles sending out the data. The receivers can be somewhat unreliable, thus the need for an extensive retry mechanism.
- One process that read the metrics from the shared metrics queue, exposes them on a Prometheus endpoint and submits them to an external timeseries database upon completion.

What we already have is a thread- and process-safe method to log (thanks loguru). What I am looking for is a similar pattern to submit metrics.

Ideally something along:

```
from utils.metrics import metric_logger

def some_function(some_data):
    ...
    metric_logger.processed_data()
    logger.info("processed data!")
    ...
```

What we do right now is to share and pass along the reference to the queue, but this in my eyes not a thing of beauty and since we're doing this for the logger, why not for a metrics-logger as well?

I would be keen to know how other teams handle this, as we can't be the only team that face this issue. The multiprocess setup is somewhat arbitrary, but it underlines the complete complexity and need for a thread- and process-safe implementation.

As of today, I can't really think of a nice solution, except to share a reference to the global metrics-queue and somehow instantiate it upon forking the processes correctly. Or to "abuse" the logger and have a separate process running that reads the logs and extracts the metrics from it. This would work well in our case, where we deploy our code in a Kubernetes cluster, but would defeat the purpose of having a pure in-Python solution.